# How to abstract over different byte buffer types? (NSData, [UInt8], …)

Tags: swift

There are different ways to access a byte buffer in Swift, the most general would probably be through a `UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>` while the actual storage can be in `NSData`, `[UInt8]`, `ContiguousArray<UInt8>`, or something else.

If I'm writing library code, I'd like it to be as general as possible and adapt to the User's choice of byte buffer while still making it as convenient to use as possible. My current code looks like this:

```
import Foundation

func stringFromUTF8Bytes(bytes: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) throws -> String {
    if let s = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return s
    } else {
        throw Error.StringEncodingFailure
    }
}

func stringFromUTF8Bytes(bytes: ContiguousArray<UInt8>) throws -> String {
    return try bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer(stringFromUTF8Bytes)
}

func stringFromUTF8Bytes(bytes: [UInt8]) throws -> String {
    return try bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer(stringFromUTF8Bytes)
}

func stringFromUTF8Bytes(data: NSData) throws -> String {
    return try data.withUnsafeBufferPointer(stringFromUTF8Bytes)
}

enum Error: ErrorType {
    case StringEncodingFailure
}
```

This is a simple solution, but it is a bit repetitive.
I thought about a more general solution:

```
protocol BufferType {
    func withUnsafeBufferPointer<R>(@noescape body: (UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R
}

func stringFromUTF8BytesGeneric(bytes: BufferType) throws -> String {
    return try bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
        if let s = String(bytes: ptr, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            return s
        } else {
            throw Error.StringEncodingFailure
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can easily implement this protocol for `NSData`:

```
extension NSData: BufferType {
    func withUnsafeBufferPointer<R>(@noescape body: (UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
        let bytesBufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes), count: length)
        return try body(bytesBufferPointer)
    }
}
```

But I cannot find a way to implement this protocol for generic types, e.g. for `[UInt8]`:

```
// error: constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Array' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause
extension Array<UInt8>: BufferType { }

// error: same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic
extension Array: BufferType where Element == UInt8 { }
```

My questions:

- Is there a way to implement the `BufferType` protocol for e.g. `[UInt8]` but not other types like `[NSWindowController]`?
- In contrast to the first point, would it actually make sense to allow arbitrary arrays? I don't think so, but maybe I'm missing something?
- Is there a better solution for what I'm trying to do (abstracting over different byte buffer types) which I'm completely missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Well, I did find one working solution myself while typing up this question… so in order to not waste that effort I'm going to post my own answer. And maybe there are other, better solutions.)

You can make a "generic" `BufferType` protocol and constrain not the protocol implementation, but the actual usage of the protocol. This is similar to how `SequenceType` is used in the standard library.

```
protocol BufferType {
    typealias Element
    func withUnsafeBufferPointer<R>(@noescape body: (UnsafeBufferPointer<Element>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R
}

extension NSData: BufferType {
    typealias Element = UInt8
    func withUnsafeBufferPointer<R>(@noescape body: (UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
        let bytesBufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes), count: length)
        return try body(bytesBufferPointer)
    }
}

extension UnsafeBufferPointer: BufferType {
    func withUnsafeBufferPointer<R>(@noescape body: (UnsafeBufferPointer<Element>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
        return try body(self)
    }
}

extension Array: BufferType { }
extension ContiguousArray: BufferType { }

func stringFromUTF8BytesGeneric <BT: BufferType where BT.Element == UInt8> (bytes: BT) throws -> String {
    switch(bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer { String(bytes: $0, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) }) {
    case let .Some(str): return str
    case .None: throw Error.StringEncodingFailure
    }
}
```

It does require adding the generic constraint to every method that uses a `ByteBuffer`, but otherwise it works exactly as I want:

```
// both print "ABC"
print(try stringFromUTF8BytesGeneric([65, 66, 67]))
print(try stringFromUTF8BytesGeneric(ContiguousArray<UInt8>([65, 66, 67])))
```